# How do I make a button close an image?

Tags: html

I'm an absolute noob with coding and have to code a website for school now. I'm trying to create a button that shows an image, which I got now with the code down below. What I want now is to create another button which makes the image close again. I have googled around but can only find things explaining how to make a button go back to another page, but I only want it to close the image, can anyone help?

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>click</title>
  <style>
           #image{
                display:none;
      }
      </style>
</head>
  <body>
      <div>
           <img src="imgpinnwand/flyer_NEU.png" width=800 height=400 id="image" alt="Flyer" />
      </div>

      <button type="button" onclick="imageShow()"><img src="imgpinnwand/Postit.png" width=400 height=400></button>

       <script>
             function imageShow(){
                    document.getElementById('image').style.display = "block";       
                    }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) is the complete guide of how to create model image.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```